# getc(fp) causing trouble

Tags: c, eof, getc

Here is my code.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    char a;
    a=9;
    FILE * fp;
    fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    while(a!= EOF)
    {
        a=fgetc(fp);
        printf("\n%d",a);
    }
}
```

The output to this is alright but at the end I am getting a weird character with -1 (since I am printing integer value.

How to stop it at `EOF` only?
Also what is this character?

Comment: don't forget to check fopen() return value

Comment: and do not forget the fclose()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the methods in the other answers, you can also do like this:

```
while ((a = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

Now you have a few alternative solutions. :)

**Edit:** As R.. so kindly reminds us, you also have to change the type of `a` to `int`.

Comment: this is the most-seen solution in C

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the `EOF` character (the `-1`) as you do not check if `EOF` was encountered immediately after `fgetc()`. Change the structure of the loop to:

```
int a; /* not char, as pointed out by R... */

for (;;)
{
    a = fgetc(fp);
    if (EOF == a) break;
    printf("\n%d", a):
}
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem that `a` has the wrong type (`char` instead of `int`)...

Comment: Yes, but just in hopes of getting OP to notice the correct answer below before blindly accepting something. Removed it now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `a` have type `int`, as that type is the return type of `fgetc()`, and is needed to represent EOF correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you stop the `while` with this condition:

```
do {...}while(a != EOF)
```

I suppose that a got EOF value **AFTER** read it.
So, you do the cycle an extra time

Comment: This will run through the loop at least once, and still print `-1` if `fgetc` returns `EOF` immediately.